# Magento2 Soap service not working

Tags: soap, magento2

I tried to create a soap service but somehow its wsdl url is not working. Below is the code:-
Api/CustomapitInterface.php

```
namespace W3solver\Customapi\Api;

interface CustomapiInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $name Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function name($name);
}
```

model/Customapi.php

```
    <?php
namespace W3solver\Customapi\Model;
use W3solver\Customapi\Api\CustomapiInterface;

class Customapi implements CustomapiInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $name Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function name($name) {
        return "Hello, " . $name;
    }
}
```

etc/di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="W3solver\Customapi\Api\CustomapiInterface" type="W3solver\Customapi\Model\Customapi" />
</config>
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="W3solver_Customapi" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/customapi/name/:name" method="GET">
        <service class="W3solver\Customapi\Api\CustomapiInterface" method="name"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

I have created this by using a refrence from http://inchoo.net/magento/api-magento/magento-2-custom-api/. I did not where this get wrong.

Below is the url i am trying to use:-
http://magento2.local/index.php/soap/default?wsdl&services=w3solverCustomapiV1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 has API access to anonymous APIs disabled by default, you will need to enable this from the backend administration panel.

To disable this feature, log in to the Admin panel and select

> Stores > Configuration > Services > Magento Web API > Web API Security.

Then select Yes from the Allow Anonymous Guest Access menu.

You can find more information on the dev guidelines [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/anonymous-api-security.html).

Comment: It work but i did not understand, how it was working earlier when I followed the same module as in http://inchoo.net/magento/api-magento/magento-2-custom-api/

Comment: Were you accessing some API that was using authentication perhaps? Because this setting apply only to APIs that are using the `mine` or `anonymous` resource.